# HTML5 Canvas: How can I check if a stroke is crossing an other stroke?

Tags: html, canvas

How can I check if a stroke is crossing any other stroke? Is this possible?

I tried with `ispointInPath()` and `ispointInStroke()`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both strokes are line segments you can test if they intersect using this test by Paul Bourke:

```
// Get interseting point of 2 line segments (if any)
// Attribution: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/
function line2lineIntersection(p0,p1,p2,p3) {

    var unknownA = (p3.x-p2.x) * (p0.y-p2.y) - (p3.y-p2.y) * (p0.x-p2.x);
    var unknownB = (p1.x-p0.x) * (p0.y-p2.y) - (p1.y-p0.y) * (p0.x-p2.x);
    var denominator  = (p3.y-p2.y) * (p1.x-p0.x) - (p3.x-p2.x) * (p1.y-p0.y);        

    // Test if Coincident
    // If the denominator and numerator for the ua and ub are 0
    //    then the two lines are coincident.    
    if(unknownA==0 && unknownB==0 && denominator==0){return(null);}

    // Test if Parallel 
    // If the denominator for the equations for ua and ub is 0
    //     then the two lines are parallel. 
    if (denominator == 0) return null;

    // If the intersection of line segments is required 
    // then it is only necessary to test if ua and ub lie between 0 and 1.
    // Whichever one lies within that range then the corresponding
    // line segment contains the intersection point. 
    // If both lie within the range of 0 to 1 then 
    // the intersection point is within both line segments. 
    unknownA /= denominator;
    unknownB /= denominator;

    var isIntersecting=(unknownA>=0 && unknownA<=1 && unknownB>=0 && unknownB<=1)

    if(!isIntersecting){return(null);}

    return({
        x: p0.x + unknownA * (p1.x-p0.x),
        y: p0.y + unknownA * (p1.y-p0.y)
    });
}
```

Otherwise, you can test if one stroke intersects any other stroke using pixel hit-testing:

- Draw all strokes except the target stroke on canvas#1.
- Draw the target stroke on canvas#2.
- Use `context.getImageData` to get the pixel data for both canvases.
- Compare both canvas's pixel data. If both canvases have a non-transparent pixel at the same location then the target stroke overlaps another stroke.

```js
var canvas1=document.getElementById("canvas1");
var ctx1=canvas1.getContext("2d");
var canvas2=document.getElementById("canvas2");
var ctx2=canvas2.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas1.width;
var ch=canvas1.height;

// draw test stroke on canvas#1
ctx1.beginPath();
ctx1.arc(150,100,50,0,Math.PI);
ctx1.lineWidth=3;
ctx1.stroke();

// draw target stroke on canvas#2
ctx2.beginPath();
ctx2.arc(150,175,50,0,Math.PI,true);
ctx2.lineWidth=3;
ctx2.strokeStyle='red';
ctx2.stroke();

// report if the target stroke intersects with any other stroke
alert('Assert: The red target intersects any other stroke: '+intersects());

function intersects(){
  // get the pixel data for both canvases
  var data1=ctx1.getImageData(0,0,cw,ch).data;
  var data2=ctx2.getImageData(0,0,cw,ch).data;
  // test all corresponding pixels 
  // data[i+3] is the opacity value so if both data[i+3]'s are
  // non-zero, then both canvases have strokes at that pixel
  for(var i=0;i<data1.length;i+=4){
    if(data1[i+3]>0 && data2[i+3]>0){
      return(true);
    }
  }
  return(false);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<h4>The Other stroke(s)</h4>
<canvas id="canvas1" width=300 height=300></canvas>
<h4>The target stroke to test if it overlaps others</h4>
<canvas id="canvas2" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```